C# - WPF - Display list of strings
When I search the equivalent of foreach in xaml WPF, I get ItemControl tutorials, but it is only about presentation
it does not solve the iteration part of it
how do I do this in WPF ???
<TextBox Text ={Binding someArray[0]}/>
<TextBox Text ={Binding someArray[1]}/>
<TextBox Text ={Binding someArray[2]}/>
<TextBox Text ={Binding someArray[3]}/>
...

but dynamically, as a loop, INSIDE the template, no codebehind
can't believe there is no tutorial to do such a simple use case
thanks for your help on this one

Does this answer your question? How do you create box for each element of array automatically in xaml?

TextBox or TextBlock - do you want the content of the array to be editable?

I found the solution like this
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding someArray}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

